# How to get the body of a particular formatted SMS in iPhone programmatically?

Tags: iphone, sms

1. I am looking for an API or any other way through which I can read an SMS from iPhone INBOX. Actually I am trying to develop an application that will read particular tagged SMS's from the iPhone INBOX and display to the user when he runs the application.
2. Anybody knows ..how to make an applications own internal folder on iPhone?
   If yes, then how to store a particular SMS to that location and read when my application is opened?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to do this through the iPhone SDK. Sandboxed applications do not have access to the SMS database.

If you have a Jailbroken phone, SMSes are stored in an SQLite database is at /var/root/Library/SMS/sms.db on the phone.