# How to see incoming txts on iPhone

Tags: iphone, text, sms, text-files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS 4 has an In-App SMS SDK for sending messages, but is there a way to have your App receive incoming SMS messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121577/ios-4-has-an-in-app-sms-sdk-for-sending-messages-but-is-there-a-way-to-have-your)

I want to be able to use incoming texts in my app.  Is there a way to get the info from a new text programmatically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 4 has an In-App SMS SDK for sending messages, but is there a way to have your App receive incoming SMS messages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121577/ios-4-has-an-in-app-sms-sdk-for-sending-messages-but-is-there-a-way-to-have-your) and [how-to-get-the-body-of-a-particular-formatted-sms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649879/how-to-get-the-body-of-a-particular-formatted-sms-in-iphone-programatically)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access that using the SDK.

If you want to develop for Jailbroken phones only you can.